# Using gamesparks RTDataBuilder to send a string, IndexOutOfRange Exception occurs if the index is greater than 128

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gamesparks

If the index is greater than 128 then we get "IndexOutOfRange Exception" in unity.

```
using (RTData data = RTData.Get())
  {
      data.SetVector3(129, v); // Exception here
      data.SetString(129, "Checking");   // Exception here
      gameSparksRTUnity.SendData(4, GameSparksRT.DeliveryIntent.RELIABLE, data);
}
```

Is there no way to send vector3 or string with a index greater than 128 ? Or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no way to send vector3 or string with a index greater than
>   128 ? Or am I doing something wrong

No and you are not doing anything wrong. This is a limitations imposed by Gamesparks.

When `RTData.SetVector3` or similar function is called, it invokes the `RTData.SetRTVector` function which sets a local array variable named `data`.

This is how that array variable is declared:

```
internal RTVal[] data = new RTVal[0x80];
```

`0x80` [converted](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) to decimal is `128` so you can only use values between `0` and `127` just like you would in any array in C#.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way I can send more than 128 vectors in one go. Seemed a long shot anyway.

Comment: Nope. That thing is hard-coded right there. Maybe there is a reason they chose 128. I don't know but you can't. By the way, I think that `0` to `128` is enough. If not enough then use json to serialize array of `Vector3` then send with `SetString`.

Comment: yep that's what I was doing initially. But it takes away too many bytes... anyways thanks for all the help